# How to indicate that a (TypeScript) parameter type must be exactly one of two types (and not the union)?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an argument and a processing function, and always returns a tuple. How can I tell typescript that if I pass one type of argument, the processing function can accept only that type, and if I pass the other type, the processing function will be able to accept that one instead? I have boiled my problem down to the below:

```js
type one = number[]
type two = Record<string, number[]>

function proc_one(arg: one): [number] {
  console.log(arg)
  return [1]
}

function proc_two(arg: two): [number] {
  console.log(arg)
  return [2]
}

function myfun<T>(
  arg: T extends one ? one : T extends two ? two : never,
  process: T extends one ? typeof proc_one : T extends two ? typeof proc_two : never
) {
  /* 
  Argument of type 'two | one' is not assignable to parameter of type 'one & two'.
  Type 'two' is not assignable to type 'one & two'.
    Type 'two' is missing the following properties from type 'number[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
  */
  return process(arg)
}

// should work
myfun([1], proc_one)
myfun({two: [2]}, proc_two)

// should error
myfun([1], proc_two)
myfun({two: [2]}, proc_one)
```

How can I write my type constraints to achieve this?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4&ssl=32&ssc=28&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA9gdtAvFOBXAtgIwgJwNoC6AsAFCiRTADuMUyAShAMYw4AmAPAM7A4CWcAOYAaFBmz4CAPlKkAZqjhNgfeFDA4YTAPrwIACgCGOQQC5YCAJTm8aLLgJQA3qShQWcLjAA2EAHTeMIJGJpauUDgQwKg4cFB4AIzEJAC+siQKSipqGlra1DAhZpQ01vF2Eo4uJG4eXr4BQUVhNRFRMXF4AEzJaSTyisqqceggmRwAKlL64cbFE1AQAB7AEHBsXBbQAPxbUOYLy6vrmwVQu2fmCABuuMLhuUwQXFwHiytrG3sX4BAwcupNDo9PsoIcPicSrQfpB-oC8pcUBBbjhSJZnOEAPQAKig4QAgiYMGtgLAAeRoAByM4AHy2lKgfE2cBgpMMLz4gjghkwvkotDAxkM6CiuDJlF+UEpIIAZFDKX5whNJdSaAymShWVB2VxOdzedBgLQKVLZfLFa03MqKKqYOrNugmbqhJQABbQOQ+QJUASCeGQHAqZ5QOSadASm0VXCESnmXxCYCu0RgGBgZOoLhJ9zwJiGYCiQzrKBdABsUHQrH84WxmPCkWisXhTxezVIfVImMxUEzMFQ3jYUBoOAA1qRRpl9IkCMmgborGOxop9E4CjYeikZwjSulO93Xb3+4scJpUSRx0up5udAUWue4MvV-F11e5xBLEA)

Comment: Constrain `T` to `One | Two` and write both `arg` and `process`  in terms of `T` like [this Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7OXrN).  Note that you're not really constraining `T` to "exactly" `One` or `Two`.... It might be `One | Two`, but in practice that's usually not an issue.  See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808 for the suggestion to be able to constrain things like that natively.  Does that meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I would like to avoid having to write the process function signature in terms of the generic type if at all possible.

Comment: @jcalz I can use a helper type to generate the method type signature, so your solution will work for my purposes.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand either of your last two comments.  You're saying you want to avoid writing `process: (arg: T) => [number]`?  In favor of what?  And what does the helper type do?  Can you maybe show me with a playground link in the comments? (https://tsplay.dev can shorten links to the playground)

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid writing `process: (arg: T) => [number]` because I don't want to have to edit that type signature anytime my processing functions change. The helper type takes T and generates the desired processing function type signatures. [Playground Demo](https://tsplay.dev/w2aBjW).

Comment: Oh, okay.  That's the same code as mine; you just gave the type a name.  I suppose that's what you mean by a "helper type".  I'm happy to give that a name in my answer also, but it's identical in terms of the type system.  I'll write up an answer when I get the chance.

Comment: ". . . I'm happy to give that a name in my answer also . . ." No need, I was trying to say that your answer works for my purposes as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript type checker can't really verify much about the behavior of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  So even if you were positive that a type like `T extends One ? typeof proc_one : T extends Two ? typeof proc_two : never` would behave properly with respect to `T`, the compiler can't see it.  Trying to call `process(arg)` when `process` is of a generic conditional type will almost certainly result in an error.  In situations where such an approach is necessary, you need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the error.

Luckily your code doesn't seem to need conditional types.  Instead, you can [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#conditional-type-constraints) the `T` type parameter to the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `One | Two`, and then have `process` be of type `(arg: T) => [number]` (or an equivalent type):

```
function myfun<T extends One | Two>(
  arg: T,
  process: (arg: T) => [number]
) {
  return process(arg); // okay
}

myfun([1], proc_one); // okay
myfun({ two: [2] }, proc_two) // okay

myfun([1], proc_two) // error
myfun({ two: [2] }, proc_one) // error
```

Now everything behaves as expected.  The compiler is happy to allow `process(arg)` because `process()` takes a single argument of type `T`, which is the type of `arg`.

That's basically it, but the phrasing of the question as accepting "exactly" one member of the union leads me to talk a little more.  TypeScript doesn't really have a great way to say that a generic type parameter must be *exactly* one type; the constraint `T extends One | Two` allows `T` to be `One` or `Two` as desired, but it also allows it to be the full `One | Two` union.  Usually this situation won't crop up, since your `arg` argument is unlikely to be of type `One | Two`.  But it technically can happen:

```
myfun(Math.random() < 0.5 ? [1] : { two: [2] }, (x: One | Two) => [3]); // okay
```

That code is still safe here, but it might be unexpected.  We'd like to say "`T` should be exactly one of `One` or `Two`", but there is no direct support for that.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) for an open feature request for such functionality.

For now, I'd say leaving open the possibility that someone passes in `One | Two` isn't a big deal for the example here, and any effort to prevent it will just make your code more fragile.  So that's a good place to leave it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4&ssl=16&ssc=32&pln=15&pc=10#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdtAvFOBXAtgIwgJwNoC6AsAFCiRQAqA7gPZTIBKEAxrTgCYA8AzsDgEs4AcwA0KDNnwEAfKVIAzVHBbABtOFDA5aLAPoaIACgCGOYQC5YCAJRW8aLLgJQA3qShQ2cHrQA2EAB0frTCpuY2HlA4EMCoOJp4AIzEJAC+8iRKKmoaWjr6wHThllR0dlAOks5uUd6+AcGhJZEknjFxCZUATKkZJIrKquqa6CDZXJRQEAAewBBwHDzW0AA+ZbQyRlFmpZSiUdq6EDw8ViVWlDYMMpWOUqnX7m3RsfGaRywnPC2k-aRjbJGZIEcSfAy2ADcUAA9DCoLQANYmEAA8bKIyuKBFWj2XpQNJggp6HHXOEI5GogYkQEYkFE3Qk8qw+G4HQ4NFArE4vEuQn5RmGMmsnDszK0uBGACyJmAAAtAjgTItaOgjNcuFAAAyBACsUAA-JUUlArNy6LyCeIjDMrPA1htrohbngAMwEGzQ8lIlFAA)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this thoughtful response. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
type Args = [arg: one, process: typeof proc_one] | [arg: two, process: typeof proc_two];

const myfun = function (...args: Args) {
  const arg = args[0];
  const process = args[1];

  if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
    const typedArg = arg as one;
    const typedProcess = process as typeof proc_one;

    return typedProcess(typedArg);
  }

  const typedArg = arg as two;
  const typedProcess = process as typeof proc_two;

  return typedProcess(typedArg);
};
```

Comment: To be clear, I need it to not depend on the shape of the data. What I've shown here is quite simplified from the actual shapes of the data being passed.